# Cannot read property 'ids' of undefined Error

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm trying out a simple sample from this github repo i.e [link](https://github.com/wesleygrimes/angular-ngrx-chuck-norris). Everything worked before I add the product store where I created new model, Action, effect and reducer.

But, now I'm getting

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ids' of undefined

I have added my code in stackblitz for reference. Please let me know what is that I'm doing wrong. Here is the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-347wt1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figure out the culprit, it was me :) , there was a typepo error in the name of the FeatureStore used at the time of registering the store in compared to the storename used while creating the FeatureSelector. Thanks to all who tried to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error happens when you try to access a property of an undefined object (undefined.ids). When you have a store, it is quite likely that when accessing the property it is undefined (because of an asynchronous call e.g.). What you can do is to either init it in the store or to filter the undefined values out before you access the property: `anyObservable$.filter(o => !!o).map(o => o.ids)`